# redirect external url only as query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to redirect all external links thru a php file with the url of the external site set as a variable.

Example. If my site (mysite.com) has a link to `google.com/results/1234` I'd like to automatically rewrite the url to something linke `mysite.com/external.php?p=google.com/results/1234.`

I'd like an htaccess solution, as I am unable to change files associated with external urls without affecting other urls on the site.

I DO Not want to redirect any link with mysite.com.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Once outgoing external links are generated, you have no control over them. The source of them, the code that generates them inside your site, is what might be modified, but it is missing in your question.

Comment: That really makes alot of sense. Thank you faa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not feasible via .htacess file. .htaccess can ONLY rewrite incoming URLs with domain names that resolve to your web server. It has no control over outgoing URLs as these requests are directly going to outgoing web servers (in your example, google.com).

What you probably need is a scripting solution that redirects the user as you desire by hooking in to `onclick` events of all the links.

**EDIT:** Here's a quick proof of concept using jQuery. This should get you started.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>jQuery global redirector</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://google.com/search?q=jquery">google url would redirect</a><br />
 <a href="http://mysite.com/somepage.php">mysite.com url won't redirect</a>
 <script>
 <!--
    $("a").click(function(e) {
      var url = e.target.href;
      if(!(url.startsWith("http://mysite.com") || url.startsWith("mysite.com"))) {
        window.location.href = "http://mysite.com/redirect.php?site=" + url;
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
 //-->
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should probably put the script inside another file (say redirect.js) and then include this script (near the end of <html>) selectively in your pages that need such redirection. And don't forget to import jQuery as well!

Comment: Thank you Ravi for this solution! I didn't think to use jquery. Do you have any opinion on how this technique will affect seo? I'm wondering if I still have a chance for leaks thru the hard coded links when bots visit the site.

Comment: This would neither push the ranking up nor down. It's neutral from SEO perspective since the `<html>` text remains exactly the same - the links in your articles etc. remain the same. In fact, your link <a> tags are not even touched (like adding an onclick="" handler to them) and that's the beauty of jQuery.